# Json Result MVC Controller to Google Map via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, google-maps

I have a problem because i want to use this Json Result that returns Json List but my problem is how should i call the json result that i will be using to geocode and add marker to my Google Maps ? I used getJson and its not functioning but i dont tried yet the .ajax function

Here is my sets of codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var geocoder;
    var map;

    function initialize() {
        var minZoomLevel = 4;
        var zooms = 7;
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: minZoomLevel,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.50, -90.50),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        // Bounds for North America
        var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
     new google.maps.LatLng(15.70, -160.50),
     new google.maps.LatLng(68.85, -55.90)
   );

        // Listen for the dragend event
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function () {
            if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;

            // We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds

            var c = map.getCenter(),
         x = c.lng(),
         y = c.lat(),
         maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
         maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
         minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
         minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

            if (x < minX) x = minX;
            if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
            if (y < minY) y = minY;
            if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
        });


        // Limit the zoom level
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
            if (map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel) map.setZoom(minZoomLevel);
        });


    }
    var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
    function codeAddress() {
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    $.getJson("Dashboard/DashboardIndex",null , function(address) {

        $.each(address, function () {
            var currVal = $(this).val();
            address.each(function () {
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': currVal }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            icon: iconBase + 'man.png',
                            position: results[0].geometry.location,
                            title: currVal
                        })


                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                            return function () {
                                infowindow.setContent(currVal);
                                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                            }
                        })(marker, currVal));
                        address.push(marker);
                    }
                    else if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
                        setTimeout(codeAddress, 2000);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                    }
                    });
});
                });
            });
        return false;
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        initialize();
        codeAddress();

    }
</script>
```

And my JsonResult at my Controller

```
public JsonResult LoadWorkerList()
    {
        var workerList = new List<Worker_Address>();

        // check if search string has value
        // retrieve list of workers filtered by search criteria
        var list = (from a in db.Worker_Address
                    where a.LogicalDelete == false
                    select a).ToList();



        List<WorkerAddressInfo> wlist = new List<WorkerAddressInfo>();
        foreach (var row in list)
        {
            WorkerAddressInfo ci = new WorkerAddressInfo
            {
                ID = row.ID,
                Worker_ID = row.WorkerID,
                AddressLine1 = row.Address_Line1 + " " + row.Address_Line2+ " " +row.City + " "+ GetLookupDisplayValById(row.State_LookID),
                LogicalDelete = row.LogicalDelete

            };
            wlist.Add(ci);
        }


        return Json(wlist.ToList().OrderBy(p => p.AddressLine1), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Im thanking some who could help me in Advance :)

Comment: Any errors in the console? If you use Chrome you can press F12 to open the console and if you use firefox you can press control + shift + k (or install firebug plugin and press F12). If an XHR request is made they should show up in the console as well with the response code and response headers (click on it)

Comment: One thing that I would like to know is why this: `var currVal = $(this).val();` the this value should refer to JSON data if I understand the code correctly. Could you post the output of the following: `console.log(this);`? put that just before setting currVal.

Comment: @HMR Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined  

It Errors on $.each(address, function () {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to guess where it goes wrong since you didn't post the JSON format and are getting errors (toLowerCase) of code you haven't posted. I think it's in the following area:

```
   function codeAddress() {
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    $.getJson("Dashboard/DashboardIndex",null , function(address) {
        console.log("full json object",address);//<--should show an array of objects
        $.each(address, function () {
            console.log(this);//<--here you can see what the JSON object is
            var currVal = this["AddressLine1"];//<--guess from what your C# code looks like
            //next each doesn't make much sense unless you have an array of arrays
            // but the C# code makes json for a list (not a list of lists)
```

You can use IE for your console output but don't bother posting the output here because I can already tell you it's going to be [Object, object]. To get useful info you're going to have to use firefox with firebug or Chrome. To see the console you can press F12

The line:

```
setTimeout(codeAddress, 2000);
```

Could be optimized since now when you are making too many requests you'll fetch the entire address list again and start from the beginning instead of "waiting" for 2 seconds and continue where you were.

The following code:

```
map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
```

Why set the center of the map within the loop? It'll just end up having the center of the last found address so you may as well do it outside the loop to set the center to last found address.

Comment: I find this Helpful and The Correct Answer but i dont have Reputations to upvote this !! Thanks sir HMR !! 

I think this line Corrects me `var currVal = this["AddressLine1"];`

Comment: @RenTao Don't worry about the up vote. Good to hear it solved your problem.